# SAPUI5 DatePicker how to forbid manual / keyboard entry while change the date through calendar is possible?

Tags: datepicker, calendar, sapui5

I would like on my DatePicker to force the user to use the calendar and not the keyboard to enter a date.
How can I do that ? I've tried readonly but that does not work.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS since ultimately the code is HTML.

```xml
<DatePicker class="disabledInput"/>
```

```css
.disabledInput input.sapMInputBaseInner {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Another way would be to extend the standard sap.m.DatePicker to put `disabled` attribute for this input field as well.